If $f: A \rightarrow B$, $g: B \rightarrow C$, and $h: C \rightarrow D$ are functions such that $H = h(g(f(x)))$ for $x$ in $A$
Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be non-empty sets, and let $f : A \rightarrow B$, $g : B \rightarrow C$, and $h : C \rightarrow D$ be functions such that the composition $H = h \circ g \circ f : A \rightarrow D$ is a bijection.
If $H$ is bijective, does this require that $h$ be bijective?
I first tried to prove $h$ needs to be injective, but got stuck because $H$ has domain $A$ not $C$.
My attempt: If $h(c) = h(c')$ where $c$ does not equal $c'$, then let $H(x) = h(c)$ and $H(y) = h(c')$ $ $ I tried to show this implied $x$ does not equal $y$, contradicting the definition of $H$, but have been unable to come up with an effective method.
Any explanation on the method required would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

$h$ must be surjective (why?), but doesn't have to be injective. Try to think of a counterexample.

HINT: $A =\{1,2\}$, $B=\{3,4\}$, $C=\{5,6,7\}$, $D=\{7,8\}$.
Take $f: A \rightarrow B$ to be $f(x)=x+2$.
Take $g: B \rightarrow C$ to be $f(x) = x+2$.
Take $h: C \rightarrow D$ to be $f(x) = \min\{x+2,8\}$.
Then $h \circ g \circ f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $D$. Is $h$ injective though?
